# Rails: Date.parse vs string.to_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is any difference between

```
Date.parse("2018-05-10")
```

and

```
"2018-05-10".to_date
```

if one is preferred over the other or if they are truly interchangeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the code [here](https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date), you'll see that the second way of doing this really just invokes the first method with only a minor check for blank-ness.

```
def to_date
    ::Date.parse(self, false) unless blank?
end
```

Regarding the `false` argument, consulting the docs [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/parse/class):

> If the optional second argument is true and the detected year is in the range “00” to “99”, considers the year a 2-digit form and makes it full.